# Rails: search in multiple model with select option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, full-text-search, sunspot

I am using sunspot gem and want to implement a search form like this 
[image]

I have two model articles and books

this is my articles model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

searchable do
  text :title
  text :content
end
```

this my books model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

searchable do
  text :title
  text :description
end
```

i want to know how to implement the search form like this where user choose what they want to search books or articles

Comment: You can submit a parameter with the search form that instructs your controller which search to do, and which results page to redirect to.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot
```

Gemfile

```
 gem 'sunspot_rails'
```

bash

```
 bundle
 rails g sunspot_rails:install
 rake sunspot:solr:start
 rake sunspot:reindex
```

models/article.rb

```
 searchable do
   text :name, :boost => 5
   text :content, :publish_month
   text :comments do
     comments.map(&:content)
   end

   time :published_at
   string :publish_month
 end

  def publish_month
    published_at.strftime("%B %Y")
  end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @search = Article.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      with(:published_at).less_than(Time.zone.now)
      facet(:publish_month)
      with(:publish_month, params[:month]) if params[:month].present?
    end
    @articles = @search.results
  end
```

articles/index.html.erb

```
 <%= form_tag articles_path, :method => :get do %>
   <p>
     <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
     <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
   </p>
 <% end %>

 <div id="facets">
   <h3>Published</h3>
    <ul>
      <% for row in @search.facet(:publish_month).rows %>
      <li>
         <% if params[:month].blank? %>
           <%= link_to row.value, :month => row.value %> (<%= row.count %>)
         <% else %>
           <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :month => nil %>)
         <% end %>
      </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ransack from activerecord-hackery.
It provides various ways to perform searching

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Rayan Bates has recorded an episode of railscasts for the same

http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack

Comment: what are the pros of ransack over sunspot?

Comment: ransack fires direct sql queries based on the filters available. But sunspot uses solr search engine to do the searching(very great if you want to search for keywords in huge paragraphs)

Comment: can i search in multiple models with select option with sunspot? because i need full text search and facet

Comment: I'm not too sure if this would work(or even makes sense). But you could give it a shot. Fetch models from the db using one(or many) search criteria using ransack. On the fetched model data, do the facet/text search using sunspot.